# Adding NSString to particular UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a coreData application, and i am saving my NSStrings and the displaying them in a UITableView using

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",person.personType];

    return cell;
}
```

I would like to make it so these results start displaying after 10 UITableView cells, and in the first 10 cells i will just add a pre-set NSString that will always be the same? Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `if` statement and check the `indexPath.row`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row < 10) {
        cell.textLabel.text = ... // some hardcoded value for the first 10 rows
    } else {
        NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row - 10 inSection:indexPath.section];
        Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:newPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = person.personType;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And your `numberOfRowsInSection` method needs to return 10 more rows too.

Comment: In Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath - 10];  The " -10" doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Why not? Please elaborate.

Comment: It break, says 'Incompatible integer to pointer conversion of type int sending to NSIndexpath'.  Could it be because of adding 10 to numberOfRowsInSection?  This is what i have in numberOfRowsInSection    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    
    return [secInfo numberOfObjects] + 10;

Comment: i did try that, but no luck

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't reading it clearly. See my latest update. You need to create a whole new index path variable with the new row and pass that to the fetched results.

Comment: "implicit conversion of long to NSIndexpath"

Comment: Are you sure you made all of the changes I did? Which line gives that error?

Comment: it's building now, thank you.  was i right where i have - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    
    return [secInfo numberOfObjects] + 10;
}

Comment: That looks correct. Keep in mind that you need update all of the table view data source and delegate methods to deal with the 10 extra rows as needed.